# Ошибка при получении SessionFactory

Tags: java, postgresql, intellij-idea, hibernate

Я пытаюсь работать с Hibernate создал Hibernate.cfg.xml в нем же:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql ">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

и в основном классе users:

```
package org.example;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jdk.jfr.Configuration;

import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    public Integer id;

    @Column(name="name")
    public String name;

    @Column(name="level")
    public Integer level;

    @Column(name="created_date")
    public Date createdDate;
```

а когда я пытаюсь прописать:`SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();`
то мне выдает ошибку:

````
Cannot resolve symbol 'SessionFactory'``` и еще 1 ошибку :```Cannot resolve symbol 'Configuration'
````

в pom.xml все классы импортировал и Hibernate и postgresql connector подключен и все сделано но ничего не помогает

Comment: 1. ошибку-то приведите. 2. и вообще: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Cannot resolve symbol 'SessionFactory'
> ```

Классы, которые не находятся, их нет в пакете по умолчанию, нужно либо импортировать, либо прописать полный и квалифицированный путь к названию класса. (FQCN)

Например:

```
org.hibernate.SessionFactory
```

Похоже, что IntelliJ IDEA автоматически импортирует пропущенные классы, и вы можете импортировать их, нажав <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> вручную.

Comment: Если этот ответ помог решить проблему, то его надо помечать галочкой и по возможности голосовать за. Так вы поможете и себе и другим, кто нуждается в решении подобной проблемы.